# Removing the taskbar transparency in uBar

Tags: dock, macos

Is there any way to remove the taskbar transparency in uBar? (i.e. set the transparency to 0%, i.e. 100% opaque)

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The version 2.3.8 that came out the day after you asked this implemented a Custom theme in Preferences that allows you to have 100% opacity.