# Start menu + taskbar for Mac OS X

Tags: macos, software-recommendation, dock

I am looking for a [start menu](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Start_menu) and [taskbar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taskbar) for Mac OS X 10.10 (Yosemite) with as many following features as possible (approximately ordered by descending importance):

Start menu:

- [Multi-column application list](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/161604/20338) (i.e. no need to scroll)
- Applications shouldn't be split into [different categories](https://askubuntu.com/q/545372/44876)
- no menu delay (i.e. the delay for opening submenus when the mouse hovers over a folder item should be 0.)
- show the X recently launched applications
- clicking on a non-leaf element of the start menu should have no effect

Taskbar:

- can be configured to have several rows
- doesn't [let other windows to go under the taskbar](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/161608/20338)
- doesn't combine windows belonging to the same application
- is not [transparent](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/161607/20338)

Is there any other great option? I am basically looking for an equivalent of [Classic Start Menu](http://ditto-cp.sourceforge.net/) (Windows).

It's okay if the suggested application provides only the start menu or the taskbar.

---

I am aware of [uBar](http://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/32318/ubar) but it [does not](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/161604/20338) present applications in a multi-column application list, clicking on a non-leaf element [opens](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/161785/20338) some folder,  and maximized windows [overlap](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/161608/20338) with the uBar's taskbar.

---

[image]

I am also aware of [iTaskbar](http://itaskbar.com/) but it has the same issues as uBar: it does not present applications in a multi-column application list, and maximized windows overlap with the taskbar.

[image]

Lastly, [Fantasktik](http://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/28378/fantasktik) is no longer maintained and doesn't work with my OS X.

Comment: Why do you want a start menu on a Mac? I use the Dock to keep my most used Applications in and the rest I do `CMD+Space` which opens up spotlight and type in the name of my app then click enter to load it. IMO it is much faster then clicking on the 'start menu' and then looking for your application that way.

Comment: @aPyDeveloper Sometimes I don't want to use a keyboard.

Comment: Ah, ok. Finder? (I am aPyDeveloper [changed name]). Also keyboard is quicker.

Comment: @iProgram I use Alfred. With that you can set up workflows so keywords open apps and/or actions.

Answer (score 1):

This is an old thread, but for anyone looking for this, ActiveDock is the best i've found so far.  Not perfect, but unfortunately uBar was just too buggy and missing some obvious features.  This seems to be working better.  https://noteifyapp.com/activedock/

Comment: have a look at my answer, hopefully you'll find my app useful

Answer (score 1):

I have developed a Windows-style Taskbar for macOS, which will make window switch and multitasking much easier. Check it out :)

https://lawand.io/taskbar/

[image]

Answer (score -1):

You can try this, [Start Menu for Mac OS X](http://www.creativengineering.it/indexEN.php#startX):

[image]

Comment: Thanks, do you know whether it has any of the features mentioned in the question? I failed to find more details on the website.